# bootstrap 3 image responsive does not work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
<div class="slid-info">
    <div class="item-logo">
        <img src="img/nlogo.png" class="img-responsive" alt="nike"/>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-caption">
        <a href="#">all model</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is a element where i have image-logo this image dont work on responsive plz help me what wrong

[image: this is my full code]

Comment: avoid putting images. instead put plunker or upload it to somewhere and put the link

Answer (score 0):

I agree with TRiNE I think you need to supply some code either in codepen or plunker etc otherwise people are quite restricted. With that said, I've just tried a dummy test in codepen and the `img-responsive` utility class works as expected there, in the sense that the image I tested with this class had been styled as expected.

Looking at your screenshot, though, and I'm clutching at straws here based the information you have provided, but is it possible that the styles you have applied to the parent div `.item-logo` are conflicting here? You are also applying the same styles from `.img-responsive` to your logo image on line 174 of styles.css - was this to prove that the utility class was not working for you?

Sorry if this isn't the answer your looking for, but if you can supply an example as suggested previously then I'd be happy to look again :)